# Custom Validation Method and Messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I working on an ASP.NET MVC website.  I'm trying to add custom validations to some fields.  The validations are firing as they should.  However, I've also added custom error messages that I want displayed.  These custom messages are not being displayed.

What am I missing?

```
<input class="text-box single-line checkAmount" 
      data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount From must be a number." 
      data-val-range="Must be within range -9999999999999999.99 and 9999999999999999.99." 
      data-val-range-max="1E+16" data-val-range-min="-1E+16" 
      data-val-required="Required." id="AmountFrom" name="AmountFrom" 
      type="text" value="0.00">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod('checkAmount', function(value, element) {
            return false; //testing
        }, 'this displays instead');
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                AmountFrom: {
                    checkAmount: true
                },
                AmountTo: {
                    checkAmount: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                AmountFrom: {
                    checkAmount: 'Amount must be greater then zero when account code selected.'
                },
                AmountTo: {
                    checkAmount: 'Amount must be greater then zero when account code selected.'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

So after walking through the validation code this is what I've found.  When I call the following:

```
$.validator.addMethod('checkAmount', function (value, element) {
    //my code from above
});

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        //my rules from above
    },
    messages: {
        //my messages from above
    }
});
```

The `$('form').validate` is called but it appears the the messages are never applied.  One reason I believe this is true is because when the validate plugin fires the following is what happens in the code:

```
$.extend($.fn, {
    validate: function(options){
        if(!this.length) {
            if(options && options.debug && window.console){
                console.warn( "Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing." );
            }
            return;
        }

        var validator = $.data( this[ 0 ], "validator" );
        if ( validator ) {
            return validator;
        }
        //REMOVED REMAING CODE FOR READABILITY
    }
});
```

So when it hits the line `if(validator) { return validator}` it returns.

Another reason is if I type `$('form').validate().settings.messages` in the Chrome's dev tool I get the messages object, one of which is **text_fkAccountCodeFrom**.  However, when I expand this object it does not have the custom message listed.  When validation run one of the internal calls is to a function called **defaultMessage**, which calls another function called `this.customMessage(element.name, method)`.  The **customMessage** function does the following:

```
customMessage: function(name, method){
    var m = this.settings.messages[name];
    return m && (m.constructor === String ? m : m[method];
}
```

When this code runs it's what would pull the custom message.  However, since the messages are never being set it pulls the default which, in my **addMethod** would display *this displays instead*.

Now if I do this:

```
$('form').validate().settings.messages.text_fkAccountCodeFrom = {checkAmount:'Required when Amount greater then zero.'};
```

I get my custom message.

So I'm not sure if it's a bug or the way things are loaded due to MVC and using unobtrusive?

Comment: Is this [Jörn Zaefferer’s jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) ?

Comment: @OIS Yes, jquery.validate.js the default that comes with ASP.NET MVC but MVC wires up validation using model annotations... which were not included in this post.

Comment: @OIS Yes, this is the jquery.validate.js.  However, we are pulling it from the Microsoft CDN.  So we are using jquery 1.11.0, jquery.validate.js 1.11.1, additional-methods.js 1.11.1 & jquery.validate.unobtrusive MVC 5

Comment: Please don't add solutions in the question itself. If you managed to find the solution yourself, you could even self answer your question + accept it. I have removed the solution part and also the *Solved* message from the title as it is not required. I have also removed the tag name from the title and improved formatting a bit.

Comment: @Harry Ok, sorry about that and thank you.  I don't typically ask a lot, so I wasn't sure how to go about it.  Again thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more searching, reading of the jquery validator api documentation and understanding how the mvc unobtrusive works I finally figured out what I needed to do.

In my custom validation method all I needed to do was the following.

```
$('form').validate().showErrors({
    'text_fkAccountCodeTo': 'Required when Amount greater then zero.'
});
```